# Choosing right timer for scheduler

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, scheduler

I'm making my own scheduler, which is going to be used in one of my WPF application.

Here is code.

```
// Interface for a scheduled task.
public interface IScheduledTask
{
    // Name of a task.
    string Name { get; }

    // Indicates whether should be task executed or not.
    bool ShouldBeExecuted { get; }

    // Executes task.
    void Execute();
    }

// Template for a scheduled task.
public abstract class PeriodicScheduledTask : IScheduledTask
{
    // Name of a task.
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    // Next task's execute-time.
    private DateTime NextRunDate { get; set; }

    // How often execute?
    private TimeSpan Interval { get; set; }

    // Indicates whether task should be executed or not. Read-only property.
    public bool ShouldBeExecuted 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return NextRunDate < DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    public PeriodicScheduledTask(int periodInterval, string name)
    {
        Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(periodInterval);
        NextRunDate = DateTime.Now + Interval;
        Name = name;
    }

    // Executes task.
    public void Execute()
    {
        NextRunDate = NextRunDate.AddMilliseconds(Interval.TotalMilliseconds);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(() => ExecuteInternal()));
    }

    // What should task do?
    protected abstract void ExecuteInternal();
}

// Schedules and executes tasks.
public class Scheduler
{
    // List of all scheduled tasks.
    private List<IScheduledTask> Tasks { get; set; }

    ... some Scheduler logic ...
}
```

Now, I need to choose right .net timer for scheduler. There should be subscribed event tick/elapsed inside, which goes through tasklist and checks whether some task should be executed and then execute it by calling `task.Execute()`.

Some more information. I need interval of timer set on 1 sec because some tasks I am creating needs to be executed every second, two, or more.

**Do I need run timer on new thread to enable user's actions on form? Which timer is most suitable for this Scheduler?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use System.Timers.Timer.  From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx):

> The server-based Timer is designed for use with worker threads in a
>   multithreaded environment. Server timers can move among threads to
>   handle the raised Elapsed event, resulting in more accuracy than
>   Windows timers in raising the event on time.

I don't think you should have to manually start it on a separate thread. I've never had it steal CPU time from the UI, although my development has been mostly in Winforms, not WPF.

Comment: Frankly, my first thought was DispatcherTimer, since my application is WPF based. If it's not neccessary run timer in different thread, what is difference between System.Times.Timer and DispatcherTimer executing taks in new thread?

Comment: @Andrew, I may have misunderstood your question. It sounds like you are concerned about the responsiveness of the UI while this timer is running. The benefit of the System.Timers.Timer in that regard is that it is designed for use in a multithreaded environment. If you do run it on a separate thread it should still fire on time regardless of what is happening in the UI. I've not used DispatchTimer, so I really can't speak about it.  It may be better for what you need, that is probably worth further research.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) as it is integrated into the dispatcher queue on the same thread that it is created (in your case the UI thread):

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
timer.Start();
```

Comment: Ok, I tried but for some reason it doesn't work. So I only changed DispatcherTimer for Timers.Timer and is't working all right. It's a mystery.

Comment: @Andrew what exactly doesn't work?  What error are you getting?

Comment: That's the thing. No errors or exceptions. Timer simply doesn't tick althought it's running according to IsEnabled property. I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Andrew are you creating the timer on the UI thread?  Try it out in an isolated test project.

Comment: This scheduler is stand-alone project. When refferenced from test project, it worked just right, even with WinForms project. But once refferenced from my another project, it doesn't work. I tried to debbug it for hours, but at last I used Timers.Timer and it's working here and there, so I don't mind.